# User input validation won't work! Still adds if I click submit even when entry slots are blank | Android development

Tags: java, android, eclipse, import

I'm trying to allow users to add themselves to a database but it keeps letting them add even when there is no input, can anyone help?

I've tried adding user input validation but it doesn't seem to be working. The problem may be very simple but im only a beginner developer with little experience any input would help, Thanks.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private Button button;
    private EditText IdText;
    private EditText NameText;
    private EditText AgeText;
    private EditText WeightText;
    private EditText HeightText;
    private EditText ReachText;
    MyDBHandler dbHandler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        IdText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.IdText);
        NameText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.NameText);
        HeightText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.HeightText);
        AgeText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.AgeText);
        WeightText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.WeightText);
        ReachText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ReachText);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        dbHandler = new MyDBHandler(this);
        AddData();


    }

    public void AddData() {

        button.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        boolean isInserted = dbHandler.insertData(IdText.getText().toString(),

                                NameText.getText().toString(),
                                AgeText.getText().toString(),
                                HeightText.getText().toString(),
                                WeightText.getText().toString(),
                                ReachText.getText().toString());
                        if (isInserted == true)
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Fighter added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        else
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data not inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        if ((IdText.getText().toString()).isEmpty())
                        {
                            IdText.setError("Please fill out your ID");

                        }

                        else if ((NameText.getText().toString()).isEmpty())
                        {
                            NameText.setError("Please fill out your Name");

                        }

                        else if ((AgeText.getText().toString()).isEmpty())
                        {
                            AgeText.setError("Please fill out your Age");

                        }

                        else if ((HeightText.getText().toString()).isEmpty())
                        {
                            HeightText.setError("Please fill out your Height in centimeters");

                        }

                        else if ((WeightText.getText().toString()).isEmpty())
                        {
                            WeightText.setError("Please fill out your weight in kilos");

                        }

                        else if ((ReachText.getText().toString()).isEmpty())
                        {
                            ReachText.setError("Please fill out your reach in inches");

                        }







                    }
                }
        );
    }







    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your checking at the beginning before adding item

Also add `return` keyword in condition so the below code will not get executed.

use this code snippet:

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if ((IdText.getText().toString()).isEmpty())
        {
            IdText.setError("Please fill out your ID");
            return;
        }

        else if ((NameText.getText().toString()).isEmpty())
        {
            NameText.setError("Please fill out your Name");
            return;
        }

        else if ((AgeText.getText().toString()).isEmpty())
        {
            AgeText.setError("Please fill out your Age");
            return;
        }

        else if ((HeightText.getText().toString()).isEmpty())
        {
            HeightText.setError("Please fill out your Height in centimeters");
            return;
        }

        else if ((WeightText.getText().toString()).isEmpty())
        {
            WeightText.setError("Please fill out your weight in kilos");
            return;
        }

        else if ((ReachText.getText().toString()).isEmpty())
        {
            ReachText.setError("Please fill out your reach in inches");
            return;
        }
        else{
            boolean isInserted = dbHandler.insertData(IdText.getText().toString(),

                    NameText.getText().toString(),
                    AgeText.getText().toString(),
                    HeightText.getText().toString(),
                    WeightText.getText().toString(),
                    ReachText.getText().toString());
            if (isInserted == true)
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Fighter added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            else
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data not inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
    }
```

Comment: you are welcome....don't forget to mark the answer as correct if it helps..